# Vue.js - onclick event doesnt fire

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue-cli project.

Inside this, I have a vue component, myList.vue, and it has these buttons:

```
<a class='button' v-on:click='changeRecord'>Aendern</a>
```

Here is a screenshot of the page with inspector on one such element:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN5SD.jpg

The changeRecord event handler is a custom method INSIDE this component. 
The code looks like this:

```
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      tableContent: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //...
    //some other code before
    //...
    changeRecord: function(event){
      console.log("clickevent fired!")
    }
  }

}
```

Now, why doesnt the event fire when I left-click the element? What do I need to do differently?

EDIT:
The markup is generated dynamically (at least the part concerning this list with the buttons). Here are the methods generating the markup:

```
fetchList: function(){
      var test = store.dispatch(USER_FETCHLIST).then((res) => {
        let tableData = res["data"]
        console.log("all tabledata ",tableData)
        var contents = ""
        var contentsHead = ""
        var contentsBody = ""

        contentsHead = this.createTableHead(tableData[0]) //Only first element is needed here!
        contents = contents + contentsHead + "<tbody>"
        contentsBody = this.createTableBody(tableData)
        contents = contents + contentsBody + "</tbody>"
        this.tableContent = contents;
      })
    },
    createTableHead: function(tableHeadData){
      console.log("all tableHeadData ",tableHeadData)
      var tableHead = "<thead><tr>"
        for (const [keyOuter, valueOuter] of Object.entries(tableHeadData)){
          if(typeof valueOuter !== 'object'){
            tableHead = tableHead + `<td>${keyOuter}</td>`
          }else if(typeof valueOuter === 'object' && valueOuter !== null){
            for (const [keyInner, valueInner] of Object.entries(valueOuter)){
              tableHead = tableHead + `<td>${keyInner}</td>`
            }
          }
        }
      //tableHead = tableHead + ""
      tableHead = tableHead + "<td>Aktion</td></tr></thead>"

      return tableHead
    },
    createTableBody: function(tableData){
      var tableBody = ""
      tableData.forEach((entry) => {
        tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>"
        for (const [keyOuter, valueOuter] of Object.entries(entry)){
          if(typeof valueOuter !== 'object'){
            tableBody = tableBody + `<td name='${keyOuter}'>${valueOuter}</td>`
          }else if(typeof valueOuter === 'object' && valueOuter !== null){
            for (const [keyInner, valueInner] of Object.entries(valueOuter)){
                tableBody = tableBody + `<td name='${keyInner}'>${valueInner}</td>`
            }
          }
        }
        tableBody =  tableBody + "<td><a class='button' v-on:click='changeRecord'>Aendern</a></td>" + "</tr>"

      })

      return tableBody
    }
```

EDIT2:
Here is the data Im generating the markup dynamically from:
I screenshotted it from the console since I think it is more readable this way due to the highlighting and stuff:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/90ipF.jpg

Comment: could you show us your html markup?

Comment: @Ifaruki see my edit in OP

Comment: screenshot of console as well?  And a demo in the question would be more useful than multiple disjointed snippets imo.  Check my answer for an example, though it's not much of an answer (yet) until I have more info.

Comment: why dont you work with the `v-for`?

Comment: @Ifaruki because Im basically entirely new to vue.js and I have some timepressure to deliver this component. I know this isnt optimal what Im doing, but if its somehow possible, I want to do it.

Comment: That's like if you purchased a lego set but then glued all the legos together, not even slotting them into each other.  And then you started complaining that it didn't connect to the lego set your friend made the normal way.  The whole point of Vue is to allow for reactive DOMs, and you're trying to use it while also manually manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @MatthewLudwig Yes, but I cant change this situation right now.

Comment: Yes you can.  Just because you've ruined half the lego set doesn't mean you have to ruin the other half.  And on top of that, this isn't legos where you've ruined some of the pieces with glue.  This is code that you can rewrite so that you don't continue to have problems caused by stumbling your way through an assignment.

Comment: And based on the words "time pressure" and "deliver" I take it that this isn't a school assignment, but instead some job you're being paid to do.  In which case, please just take the time to do it correctly.  You're either screwing the person you submit this to if they accept it or screwing yourself if they reject it due to code quality concerns.

Comment: could you show us your data strucutre in your `response.data`? so i could help you with a `v-for` loop

Comment: @Ifaruki see my EDIT2 in OP

Comment: also you're aware @baryon123 that Ifaruki asked for the data structure for the same reason I'm lecturing you.  The only difference is they seem willing to fix the code for you whereas I would prefer you understand why it's a mistake to not fix it yourself.

Comment: @MatthewLudwig I fully take responsibilty for the satisfaction of my client. Thanks for your concern, but its unnecessary.

Comment: @MatthewLudwig I have to take what _constructive_ feedback I can get, and I will. At the end of the day, the code has to run, and if its a chimera of vue.js and native JS, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with a `v-for` looks like this:

```
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Internal_Key</td>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>description_sysops</td>
    <td>aktion</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="table in tabledata" :key="table.Internal_key">
    <td>{{ table.Internal_key }}</td>
    <td>{{ table[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table)[1]][Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table)[1]])[0]] }}</td>
    <td>{{ table[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table)[2]][Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(table)[2]])[0]] }}</td>
    <td>
      <a class="button" @click="changeRecord">Aendern</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the code:

```
export default {
data() {
  return {
    tabledata: []
  };
},
methods: {
  changeRecord: function(event) {
    console.log("clickevent fired!");
  }
},
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch(USER_FETCHLIST).then(res => {

    this.tabledata = res.data;

  });
}
};
```

Comment: works like a charm so far, thank you!
However, I'll have to see if I can modify this to fully suit my needs. Right now, you have statically referenced the data inside the array. I need to do this dynamically as well, hence the foreach loops in my JS. 
It is very well possible that additional extensiontables OR less extensiontables are fetched by the user. Is there any way to accomplish such behavior with v-for?

Comment: You mean if you add new data to the array? If you add data with `array.push()` or if you set the data to a new array vuejs will automaticly only change the values that are deleted, added or changes, but i forgott to add the `key` attribute i will edit my post

Comment: The array with the data comes from my backend. There, the array is filled with data the user has access rights to. So the user might receive more, or less, or simply different datarecords. This data comes from so called "extensiontables". This is data visible only to users with access rights. So no, this is not just about the user adding new data to the list. Its about the data coming from the database, which might be different for every single user.

Comment: that means that `extensiontable_itc` could be for another use for example `extensiontable_abc`?

Comment: yeah, you could have any number and/or combination of extensiontable_XXX in each of these records^^

Comment: you can test this solution, i didnt tested it with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`

Comment: thanks, but the number of elements inside these records may change as well. Not necessarily per user, but per extensiontable_XXX. One might have description1 only, while the other has description1,description2 or whatever else.